# Vue composition API value set, but still null in catch

Tags: vuejs2, promise, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have created this logic that when doing it's happy path, everything works fine. But when there is an error, I want to display it on the interface.
My code looks like this (trimmed):

```
export function initCamera() {
  const loaded = ref(false);
  const cameras = ref([]);
  const error = ref(null);

  someTask().then((response) => {
      cameras.value = response;
  loaded.value = true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("we got an error", error);
  loaded.value = true;
      error.value = error;
      console.log(error.value);
    });

  return { loaded, cameras, error };
}
```

If there are no errors, then the interface does have access to the **cameras** and the **loaded** flag is set to true.
If there is an error, it does set the **loaded** flag, but the **error** is always null.

All the console logs you see there display a value.
My component looks like this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "TheScanner",
  directives: {
    content,
  },
  emits: ["onExpand"],
  setup() {
    let init = false;
    const result = reactive({ loaded: Boolean, cameras: null, error: null });
    const expanded = ref(false);
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();

    const expand = (value: boolean) => {
      expanded.value = value;
      instance.proxy.$emit("onExpand", value);
    };

    watch(
      () => expanded.value,
      (value) => {
        if (!value || init) return;
        init = true;
        Object.assign(result, initCamera());
        console.log(result);
      }
    );

    return { expanded, expand, ...toRefs(result) };
  },
});
```

As you can see, I have setup the **result** as a reactive property and use **Object.assign** to assign my response to it. That console log there will show the **cameras** and **loaded** boolean values, but never shows the error. It's always null.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the variable name 'error' into someting else, because you have declared  another variable named 'error' above, the ref. In catch block, the variable 'error' points the error object, not the ref.

```
export function initCamera() {
  const loaded = ref(false);
  const cameras = ref([]);
  const error = ref(null);

  someTask().then((response) => {
    cameras.value = response;
    loaded.value = true;
  })
  // Pay attention to this line
  .catch((err) => {
   console.log("we got an error", err);
   loaded.value = true;
   error.value = err;
   console.log(error.value);
  });

  return { loaded, cameras, error };
}
```